# Overlaying inside td pushes the table cell outwards

Tags: html, css

I am facing a layout problem when using overlay inside a td. Let me show my html.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function alterControl() {
            var $visibleCtrl = $("#servicesTable tbody").find("#ID1").find(".divOverlayVisible");
            var $hiddenCtrl = $("#servicesTable tbody").find("#ID1").find(".divOverlayHidden");
            $visibleCtrl.removeClass("divOverlayVisible").addClass("divOverlayHidden");
            $hiddenCtrl.removeClass("divOverlayHidden").addClass("divOverlayVisible");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="servicesTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <label id="lblServiceName">
                        Name</label>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <label id="lblResult">
                        Result</label>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr id="ID1">
            <td>
                <input style="width: 100px;" id="txtName1" name="txtName1" type="text" value="Service1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="overlayOuter">
                    <div id="ServiceTestResult1" class="divOverlayVisible">
                        <input type="text" value="This is static text" id="Testresult1" style="width: 40px;
                            height: 16px;" />
                    </div>
                    <div id="ServiceTestResultTestImage1" class="divOverlayHidden">
                        <img src="Validated_16.png" alt="Image not found" style="width: 16px; height: 16px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="btnToggle" value="Alter" onclick="alterControl()" />
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS is like below

```
.overlayOuter
{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.divOverlayHidden 
{
    top:0px; 
    left:0px;
    position:absolute; 
    visibility:hidden; 
    z-index:101;
}

.divOverlayVisible 
{
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    position:absolute; 
    visibility:visible; 
    z-index:100;
}
```

The problem that I am facing is, table cell in my second column is getting outside the row. My idea was to show textbox or image at a time based on input. Please find the screenshots too which are uploaded in skydrive
https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=EAA26C1BAE3050B8&id=EAA26C1BAE3050B8!130
https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=EAA26C1BAE3050B8&id=EAA26C1BAE3050B8!131

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Tables - Aaaah disaster, use div's for designing layouts and use tables for tabular data

Comment: I am using tables for representing tabular data, not to create layout. Is that too bad?

Comment: No, that’s not bad at all – that’s what tables are for. What’s bad though is that your posted screenshots require me to login to skydrive first to see them – no thanks. Please post a live example, using jsfiddle.net or something.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the images because I'm not member, sorry. But I've [recreate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Arkana/4JZsp/) in a jsFiddle, and, if I remove `position:absolute;` from `.divOverlayVisible` it seems to work properly: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Arkana/4JZsp/1/)

```
.divOverlayVisible {
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    /*position:absolute; I have removed this line */
    visibility:visible;
    z-index:100;
}
```

EDIT: If you need the position to make `z_index` work, you can change the value `absolute` to `relative` rather than remove it.